# Change default behavior of Visual Studio when adding new class

Tags: class, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, filenames

For instance, if I try to add a class named TestClass, Visual Studio fills filenames with TestClass.h and TestClass.cpp in the dialog.

But, I don't want to see camel case in filename and also, I prefer hpp to h for extension of C++ header file.

That is, for instance, I want to Visual Studio fill the filenames with testclass.hpp and testclass.cpp for new class named TestClass.

How can I get this? FYI, I'm using Visual Studio 2015 community edition.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and can define own templates in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\VCWizards\[MyPackOfTemplates]\TestCase\

I suppose someting simmilar should be in Visual Studio 2015. If there is something simmilar in 2015, You should find template of Your new class. Then find variable containing name of class in html\1033\default.htm
and unify name inside scripts\1033\default.js